# How do I make a url contain multiple sections? React

Tags: reactjs

So full disclosure, I'm not sure how to ask this question properly, but I do have a decent example. I'm making a React app and I'm trying to make the url more "descriptive" I suppose.

So it starts off at Home, then I go to a Products page and the url changes from /home to /products. This part is fine.

When I want to go to a specific product from the product page, I want the url to change to /products/example instead of just /example. Do I have to specify this with the Links or is there some cleaner way to get it done?

Right now my only answer is to make the link go to /product/example and have the App.js route to the same url. I'm not sure how to properly ask this question for a Google search so I had to ask it here. If you have an idea how to specifically phrase what I'm asking, I'd appreciate that too.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't know If I understand, but a route to a specific product is usually product/id

Comment: I think you could search for URL parâmetros, query strings and react-router docs

Comment: Thank you, I'll give that a go and see if I find something. It could just be that there is no method like I'm imagining in my head.

Comment: I'm not sure If I understood your question...

Answer (score 1):

I believe the `example` in your URL `/products/example` is the product name for your product. If so, this can be done in putting the product name as an URL parameter using `react-router` or `react-router-dom` if you still have not.

by declaring the route as

```
import { Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";

const Router = () => (
    <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/home" component={()=>return <h1>Home</h1>} />
        <Route exact path="/products" component={()=>return <h1>Products</h1>} />
        <Route path="/products/:productName" component={props=>return <h1>props.match.params.productName</h1>} />
    </Switch>
);

export default Router;
```

more on that [here](https://reactrouter.com/web/guides/quick-start)